How do I get the value for a color picker in R Shiny?
In my Shiny app I am trying to get the value from a color picker. Using shinyjs::onevent I can get and put the value in the input control but when I am pressing the save button (which triggers the onclick event), I am receiving just "null" or an empty value from the input control. Why input[['titleColorChart']] gives me "null" or empty instead of the right value?
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(stringr)

  jsCode <- "

shinyjs.updateColorTagValue= function(params){ 
var colorString;
colorString = JSON.stringify($('#' + params[0] + '1').val());  
colorString =  colorString.substring(1, colorString.length-1);
alert(colorString)
$('#' + params[0] + '1' ).attr('value',colorString);
$('#' + params[0]).attr('value',colorString);
 Shiny.setInputValue('#' + params[0] + '', colorString);
Shiny.onInputChange(params[0],params[1]);     
}
" 

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("updateColorTagValue")),
  div(tags$input(id = str_c("titleColorChart","1"),
                 name = str_c("titleColorChart","1"),
                 selector = str_c("titleColorChart","1"),
                 type = "color",
                 `data-role` = "color-selector",
                 value = "",
                 class = "form-control input-xs",
                 style = "width: 20px;padding: 0;border: none;/* margin: 0; */"),
      tags$input(id = str_c("titleColorChart"),
                 name = str_c("titleColorChart"),
                 selector = str_c("titleColorChart"),
                 type = "text",
                 value = "",
                 class = "form-control input-xs",
                 style = "padding: 0;border: none;/* margin: 0; */")
  ),
  tags$button(id = "save",
              type = "button",
              class = "tool-button",
              span("Save"))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

nameOfDropDownList <- "titleColorChart"
observeEvent(input[[str_c(nameOfDropDownList,"1")]], {
   input[[nameOfDropDownList]] <- input[[str_c(nameOfDropDownList,"1")]]
 
})
observe({
  input[[str_c(nameOfDropDownList,"1")]]
  output[[nameOfDropDownList]] <- renderText({
    input[[str_c(nameOfDropDownList,"1")]]
  })
})
observeEvent(input$save, {
  updateColourInput(session, "titleColorChart",
                    value = input$titleColorChart1
                    )
})


onevent("change", str_c(nameOfDropDownList,"1") ,js$updateColorTagValue(nameOfDropDownList, input$titleColorChart))
onclick("save",alert(input[["titleColorChart"]]))


}

shinyApp(ui, server)


You are trying to update the value of the ColourInput in the observeEvent on input$save, but this is never entered. Why do you define all inputs by yourself? The button e.g. needs class = "btn btn-default action-button" and titleColorChart should be defined by using colourInput (which was moved to the colourpicker package similar to updateColourInput). Then it will work.
